# How can i select any screen as initiaRouteName expo-router v2

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am using Expo project and i see that it uses expo-router v2 it looks like next js router

but the problem am facing am trying to create login and register screen insdide a folder (auth).

i want the login page to be the first to render instead of the (tabs) index

this is my folder structure

```
zar-app
├─ .git
│  ├─ COMMIT_EDITMSG
│  ├─ config
│  ├─ description
│  ├─ FETCH_HEAD
│  ├─ HEAD
│  ├─ hooks
│  │  ├─ applypatch-msg.sample
│  │  ├─ commit-msg.sample
│  │  ├─ fsmonitor-watchman.sample
│  │  ├─ post-update.sample
│  │  ├─ pre-applypatch.sample
│  │  ├─ pre-commit.sample
│  │  ├─ pre-merge-commit.sample
│  │  ├─ pre-push.sample
│  │  ├─ pre-rebase.sample
│  │  ├─ pre-receive.sample
│  │  ├─ prepare-commit-msg.sample
│  │  ├─ push-to-checkout.sample
│  │  └─ update.sample
│  ├─ index
│  ├─ info
│  │  └─ exclude
│  ├─ logs
│  │  ├─ HEAD
│  │  └─ refs
│  │     ├─ heads
│  │     │  └─ master
│  │     └─ remotes
│  │        └─ origin
│  │           ├─ HEAD
│  │           └─ master
│  ├─ objects
│  │  ├─ 03
│  │  │  ├─ 0d9510d90d8c8db6c45fb863d84bc409add846
│  │  │  └─ d6f6b6c6727954aec1d8206222769afd178d8d
│  │  ├─ 05
│  │  │  ├─ 5ad2205d2e347de1e62ec158ffce28e90a5e26
│  │  │  └─ 647d55c75215e41f54285e3ca8f7fa6466bc01
│  │  ├─ 0a
│  │  │  └─ 071b9ffa7267e5d15bb4909467651bce1d0ed9
│  │  ├─ 0b
│  │  │  └─ 37b6eb4f9a0d37626c5bde9b9ed188ef6fa0ad
│  │  ├─ 0e
│  │  │  ├─ 89705a9436743e42954d3744a0e7ff0d3d4701
│  │  │  └─ 97506215be016992001991b72b8181fd3d2d08
│  │  ├─ 0f
│  │  │  └─ 3762678b6f2f4ff8e37da0a4054b8db8c92a09
│  │  ├─ 11
│  │  │  └─ fdf651b0f6018881fed3555d0b65d2b2ed48f5
│  │  ├─ 12
│  │  │  └─ bebe9c487d2fbd2b00e589045a0769313720e4
│  │  ├─ 13
│  │  │  └─ a359ca543b5935dba543bb4983e100d535ff3d
│  │  ├─ 15
│  │  │  ├─ 8aa76b174f0390ed696bca6d12de9e74816879
│  │  │  └─ ec6fc290522d3021cf124de394a65bea729a20
│  │  ├─ 16
│  │  │  └─ 83a763ee68363ff0c05f204d0eebaff83bb7bc
│  │  ├─ 19
│  │  │  └─ 798cee82904347f21ba0942d86df91a44830e2
│  │  ├─ 1a
│  │  │  ├─ 1e77fa207d3317257556cf3d64a2dbaf05143f
│  │  │  ├─ 7d7f9f675620b421c326339426c126ac3efd3d
│  │  │  ├─ 9693d97fe25e8635691463d9d51a63ecd32aa0
│  │  │  └─ b94aef8b8035304fdcef4a89ae76a7328bed2a
│  │  ├─ 1b
│  │  │  ├─ 620043155fe3d7a031039b9f527af939924e0a
│  │  │  └─ e35aebe471c3ee1f1ce2e0d3b39ba3b7018e8a
│  │  ├─ 1c
│  │  │  └─ 706c7bb4a586e5911f4242d3d1158b97e7b658
│  │  ├─ 22
│  │  │  └─ fbceb1de5067b10a80cc324753e09887267782
│  │  ├─ 25
│  │  │  └─ 524d773a61d254ee8787d45281fc8e6a312ecf
│  │  ├─ 26
│  │  │  ├─ 262225e52f02271ee33a8abf1778cd9d5ba81d
│  │  │  └─ f657de75ab7bc14f3cdf47825e861d5523cecb
│  │  ├─ 28
│  │  │  └─ d7ff717769d29e5d1f036bfa91eea660ce8a24
│  │  ├─ 2a
│  │  │  └─ f35dcc0077b6f66d4c08a80bbc58ccc89092e8
│  │  ├─ 2b
│  │  │  └─ 5e36c0269d7ac6259a8bc8a81f8b8442aac8fe
│  │  ├─ 2c
│  │  │  ├─ 7df79c57e5b9d50aa0717c659b26ef324ae169
│  │  │  └─ 9159ac38bbd85ccbe3b45c01a027ed44526109
│  │  ├─ 2d
│  │  │  └─ eef13161801516ca8c0298a9463e4b2f85c893
│  │  ├─ 2f
│  │  │  ├─ d8b923d25aa0f7f2b253fda7d26cd6345c7d39
│  │  │  └─ ec631418b42727f75ea9a275cb6949cd7b1921
│  │  ├─ 30
│  │  │  ├─ 8529cba2bc9dde32adce0556432cd206fffe54
│  │  │  ├─ de6db6b8e045ae36d9f9da70fcdae1d9f468d5
│  │  │  └─ e025473a679c1999a27199648e0bcfe8c58e5b
│  │  ├─ 35
│  │  │  └─ 43b1365da8cb8aaf106cf4243ae07a230fd134
│  │  ├─ 39
│  │  │  └─ 7e0f422c2578e8f6f7384d277212886402e0e1
│  │  ├─ 3b
│  │  │  ├─ 1e1903613de0b31200199367ca3f6efe139629
│  │  │  └─ 8233ef3a65f99046b5dff5c6243dc352d09c0d
│  │  ├─ 3d
│  │  │  └─ 7f762a177582e7f2f2abb0366521b9fbe15539
│  │  ├─ 43
│  │  │  └─ 02ea63840f852cea5cd62b27eba6a3847d504f
│  │  ├─ 45
│  │  │  └─ b49612017579e63c52f84c3d4d34c4e93b4f59
│  │  ├─ 46
│  │  │  └─ 95aecdc90dd2433b000d145b3925ec97965612
│  │  ├─ 47
│  │  │  └─ 5c72f32bc1b6a4a4b79ca3adbeb557abd58554
│  │  ├─ 49
│  │  │  └─ 3a754edfb4c9cc6715be11f6601dcf7e0418ee
│  │  ├─ 4c
│  │  │  └─ 0907d74559cd3f6f72a36ed79a77d4c9805841
│  │  ├─ 4e
│  │  │  ├─ 60e69ac7dd7dcf37699374ef35016ab828f389
│  │  │  └─ bd1eeedd9bf183de14a012946d4992e13d31c3
│  │  ├─ 4f
│  │  │  └─ bab3c307dc7fb553bca1b7849efa2fe8d7907c
│  │  ├─ 54
│  │  │  └─ 02d8faa7bc5789bb6e66bc26839dee7223f32a
│  │  ├─ 56
│  │  │  └─ 9099605ee3a73facbb54b1aa15c1022fff3adb
│  │  ├─ 59
│  │  │  └─ cd758652c591a09b9565259393f4c8571497ad
│  │  ├─ 5b
│  │  │  └─ 9e4b57ef758540e8dd9326e4cf7f146fbea1e9
│  │  ├─ 5c
│  │  │  └─ 83a094c9b77c72bf46e41cfa3b2c3d0aefa885
│  │  ├─ 5d
│  │  │  └─ 34c3a838fd8c3c6eb556edd90c7b93d29c79e4
│  │  ├─ 5e
│  │  │  └─ cef257126454ef2837eed359b9f9d1fa14e11b
│  │  ├─ 62
│  │  │  ├─ 2033759647427918b906e1c816299f8d6cfb79
│  │  │  └─ 2abf94a708a65caacb31dc3c3004135952094a
│  │  ├─ 63
│  │  │  └─ 998461b2cc300c9fa1e71ec63575066b165877
│  │  ├─ 65
│  │  │  └─ e1556898a996db9b82a544ee755fb130543ce6
│  │  ├─ 66
│  │  │  └─ 5a7cbdacd60fb6d7b6ab02a9a59e42288a7d83
│  │  ├─ 69
│  │  │  ├─ 0629077dd211587b7e27cc72214df05e3d6b95
│  │  │  └─ e90d3b583196fa125d245496312f022b69a514
│  │  ├─ 6a
│  │  │  └─ 47db3e1bb15b40aab2524269df987b75b57359
│  │  ├─ 6b
│  │  │  └─ 94dbf81583ccb4d7356c2aa9a788805a5ccd24
│  │  ├─ 6c
│  │  │  ├─ 61d520d2379dcf010b7347664105affbf380a7
│  │  │  └─ ec1b6292a64e1d209f22869d05cfe67650e0bc
│  │  ├─ 6d
│  │  │  └─ bb464ea437ce4e621323ef2e6aa41e14a6c240
│  │  ├─ 6e
│  │  │  └─ cef18cc0b8a9017e9f22ae204055d25fba585a
│  │  ├─ 70
│  │  │  ├─ 4c1c7fecffc6465df5b3fb77087c63e7e643eb
│  │  │  ├─ 86f2bb551f171831ec79ba6137a4d4beaebfb0
│  │  │  └─ c5c6c9d7c297745b82a08fb2f52d9c859a6acf
│  │  ├─ 72
│  │  │  └─ f1f76091471c6dc1c4e05378a243373d617191
│  │  ├─ 74
│  │  │  ├─ 1907c8f8afecb9fdfc26ec86a74605a741a3c6
│  │  │  ├─ a57ca822b9d81f789d81b96c16f2a9e0c0fee8
│  │  │  └─ e9993adaf6336e4e78a4f5f9e5fdfefd570b82
│  │  ├─ 75
│  │  │  ├─ 7e9d9d21756e93d13d25ecb1673d362438700d
│  │  │  └─ edaf82f979e8e0c8d11991e9eb231d8acef109
│  │  ├─ 78
│  │  │  ├─ e2082d857c36d3da5c513181cf7284394cd5cc
│  │  │  └─ fe4ed87fa25de52360c80009c18ad445677e64
│  │  ├─ 7b
│  │  │  └─ 38503f029293d1cce9deb1aec1cd20d93fa788
│  │  ├─ 7c
│  │  │  └─ 42b2cfc716ec3ca219e499c72c232d483399a1
│  │  ├─ 7d
│  │  │  └─ 9ce65f4e6390f0cba3bcc8b3c400566c1c6f52
│  │  ├─ 7e
│  │  │  └─ f8a44ec6df070c5a4e5f10592fb886f71bd3cd
│  │  ├─ 80
│  │  │  └─ 62b1ed0438729351d15ee90a948ce7ab31534d
│  │  ├─ 81
│  │  │  └─ 93bb1174037d559aa6da174d451a33183c75ab
│  │  ├─ 82
│  │  │  └─ 2baa276cec4ac07b22a0c33221c68fe7676515
│  │  ├─ 83
│  │  │  ├─ 846d04668e00405e132fb9c6de5824cf072496
│  │  │  └─ bd1a8f76ed566b9cadb5fb6a6468353bc4073b
│  │  ├─ 87
│  │  │  └─ 7863e6a47005b849f006512a7c4d2a91ca3c52
│  │  ├─ 88
│  │  │  ├─ 729833c304c3ef092e978aafa56ed794f284c2
│  │  │  └─ 90f7202bce737d8c38164d18e829425a8735fe
│  │  ├─ 8a
│  │  │  └─ 5a50ab637b310495a60bbae22e20ab76d09ce9
│  │  ├─ 8b
│  │  │  └─ 7b632f9c05c3da44447cc0773d355e45f442c0
│  │  ├─ 8c
│  │  │  └─ 47578f5ee21be5eabd0614b8130ec095a3576a
│  │  ├─ 8f
│  │  │  └─ e63c662bd15b6364b98f61697e384a2e5f2ce8
│  │  ├─ 90
│  │  │  └─ ff3f4796982b63404dbe71071df996dc4fd8fe
│  │  ├─ 92
│  │  │  └─ b82446f1df8805484a011cd84d658d4ea07438
│  │  ├─ 93
│  │  │  └─ 6344e74c7afbe18cbb7acec8c74b5f2d4f81da
│  │  ├─ 94
│  │  │  └─ b4eaee6568d977c053e2b99d28f9095057929b
│  │  ├─ 95
│  │  │  └─ a4a168aa30e323a12aa9c68f67c9c40f5c1a43
│  │  ├─ 9a
│  │  │  └─ 69bd4fd551f9bbb24690e014cec2941c56f3dc
│  │  ├─ 9c
│  │  │  └─ ef3af06dc4ac47d9344d90df457f855c6d2be9
│  │  ├─ 9d
│  │  │  └─ ffa29afd7e1a52dc4bb81c71767b60c8cb72b9
│  │  ├─ a0
│  │  │  └─ b1526fc7b78680fd8d733dbc6113e1af695487
│  │  ├─ a1
│  │  │  └─ 4829a82572ab62ad0bfe68bc90f4346b8deb47
│  │  ├─ a2
│  │  │  ├─ 97226028fd42be345480f9324f2eceb752460c
│  │  │  └─ dbe8230dc6c8783c5f806aeaf3c14d93e88172
│  │  ├─ a3
│  │  │  └─ 2d1163ce46fb28d4ff595a0618dbc65e58b671
│  │  ├─ a4
│  │  │  └─ 28733261bc30ce3052d2fb76ec19574af12029
│  │  ├─ a6
│  │  │  └─ a67166e6c611790c17b151b7d1d955cdcc7146
│  │  ├─ a7
│  │  │  └─ 828dd68fead4eeeff4f7aa737418dd47157fc7
│  │  ├─ a9
│  │  │  └─ 066ea2f3128a23dae241b4922c33e1a2000ebf
│  │  ├─ aa
│  │  │  └─ 3977ce70cb7044b687e3b537000435903959cf
│  │  ├─ ab
│  │  │  └─ f760439be83f7dfbc2661468c05049aca03f12
│  │  ├─ ae
│  │  │  └─ 862747d3bc621be42efafd90f882940fbcae3b
│  │  ├─ af
│  │  │  └─ 426247bec4b692d4de913a715682b929deee71
│  │  ├─ b0
│  │  │  └─ 28d93c857518a0c09c25dd42b6cd60edc0efb1
│  │  ├─ b5
│  │  │  └─ fc6057247bec3e5512a04d7225337f1d498960
│  │  ├─ b6
│  │  │  └─ a18e731e8f276dd609561c367ae07f0b8a9b27
│  │  ├─ ba
│  │  │  └─ c58664c9a93ef2832941c6981a75677c7e64e0
│  │  ├─ bb
│  │  │  ├─ 266a278dd52eaef05a1e967f497b146191a8cb
│  │  │  ├─ 61569e359dc8a39ae8bfd75c4793f60fcb16a1
│  │  │  └─ ed482354db476df9adf066a22ad8b37e849aa0
│  │  ├─ c1
│  │  │  └─ 7156da92dec45bacd84a7cd7f8ffd5449ddaed
│  │  ├─ c3
│  │  │  ├─ cafe333898b97ae7014d91582639f2fa0830ff
│  │  │  └─ ef95eb16625eeee4de5525128034693e122ef1
│  │  ├─ c5
│  │  │  ├─ 033a335102e0a02c0b086b4e30a8ebc861d782
│  │  │  └─ 35be96eedd1cc17ffe0d06e3983ebd46f0358c
│  │  ├─ c9
│  │  │  ├─ d33e54ec2bee2545a2844a960fdc5d02407222
│  │  │  └─ dd3e47ecd7deb8364bf5570b4323693840f7ea
│  │  ├─ ce
│  │  │  ├─ cd9a2aac300623534f5bacedc66132e7273d0e
│  │  │  └─ e9eb11b9f4dec95f7d4bc3295bc94fd0e08b19
│  │  ├─ d0
│  │  │  └─ 0a2c13c074e9fb3ffaa20b6257fc58e7289a4e
│  │  ├─ d1
│  │  │  └─ 8342dbf88b913b1ae2b0debb3aa4e0cefebca7
│  │  ├─ d2
│  │  │  └─ 15db7b99d5595e7a8cb237f4b02359cc447645
│  │  ├─ d5
│  │  │  ├─ 30ddabb781e2193f4ef908635a2d03b11fa8a7
│  │  │  ├─ b47cfedb80b5167bcff0b7d585b3886454898e
│  │  │  └─ e4969c95ce63e08486c9fc45ab43364e9b1091
│  │  ├─ d6
│  │  │  └─ 668c49ea2db5eb28df2c6a5bd3ab90997351f1
│  │  ├─ da
│  │  │  ├─ 2a38779242f3faf1a210ce1471ea09cf9aed16
│  │  │  └─ 386b99c5f550e951e868478b8aadcd9c8ad091
│  │  ├─ e2
│  │  │  └─ 1fe9361cfcaac6cbff34e7b93395ca5b8947e3
│  │  ├─ e3
│  │  │  └─ 8dbab9654fecf30e79cbc8e4f84b753db76c4f
│  │  ├─ e6
│  │  │  └─ 8030e210275ce0eaf263ffcaf204fd6c13847b
│  │  ├─ e7
│  │  │  ├─ 0c3988e2899f1771626066082300bf28f7eee8
│  │  │  └─ 5f697b1801871ad8cd9309b05e8ffe8c6b6d01
│  │  ├─ ea
│  │  │  ├─ 48da08349e283e9bfd0dd10480d5526f2d02d9
│  │  │  ├─ 4a81993eb4444d3096ef9b8d5ebbed2a7a8da3
│  │  │  ├─ 61dfbac56a042b854d1fde3d53b1394b1dd498
│  │  │  └─ bae068a5fff1ddb9aae1e60e64602f7df62b9f
│  │  ├─ eb
│  │  │  └─ 245786f68bc4a731918b73037354eeb70b7bd4
│  │  ├─ ec
│  │  │  └─ daa20b915d63a822956ee3a7e283372944509b
│  │  ├─ ee
│  │  │  └─ 385c4c1af71e186efead68d3b7e7a19ebb7298
│  │  ├─ f0
│  │  │  └─ bd59588f551324bdc1f6bf56eb1aec70dd8af8
│  │  ├─ f2
│  │  │  └─ e30d0ac96eceae18ae4b180eecc95334299817
│  │  ├─ f5
│  │  │  └─ 69ce8d3008f0eb36d038481cc80a8b6b3ecce8
│  │  ├─ f7
│  │  │  └─ 00a90c30e77ded9ca1b7c9d72f343516ce3ec5
│  │  ├─ f8
│  │  │  └─ 78478342f1b9c3a0c809b27e95aa0d9b8d248c
│  │  ├─ fd
│  │  │  └─ ea7452f84d6b61a1c23c2c8e76a1bf0267007f
│  │  ├─ fe
│  │  │  └─ aa68d2b4999f546b15c38f0aaed717936cf8e6
│  │  ├─ ff
│  │  │  └─ 274ff739ffe8fa8425d4151ad70172d0505ed8
│  │  ├─ info
│  │  └─ pack
│  └─ refs
│     ├─ heads
│     │  └─ master
│     ├─ remotes
│     │  └─ origin
│     │     ├─ HEAD
│     │     └─ master
│     └─ tags
├─ .gitignore
├─ .vscode
│  └─ .react
├─ app
│  ├─ (tabs)
│  │  ├─ bindding.tsx
│  │  ├─ index.tsx
│  │  ├─ more.tsx
│  │  ├─ new_ad.tsx
│  │  ├─ profile.tsx
│  │  └─ _layout.tsx
│  ├─ +html.tsx
│  ├─ modal.tsx
│  ├─ [...missing].tsx
│  └─ _layout.tsx
├─ app.json
├─ assets
│  ├─ fonts
│  │  ├─ Rubik-Black.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-BlackItalic.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-Bold.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-BoldItalic.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-ExtraBold.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-ExtraBoldItalic.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-Italic.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-Light.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-LightItalic.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-Medium.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-MediumItalic.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-Regular.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-SemiBold.ttf
│  │  ├─ Rubik-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
│  │  └─ SpaceMono-Regular.ttf
│  └─ images
│     ├─ adaptive-icon.png
│     ├─ favicon.png
│     ├─ icon.png
│     └─ splash.png
├─ babel.config.js
├─ components
│  ├─ auth
│  │  └─ Login.tsx
│  ├─ Button.tsx
│  ├─ Card.tsx
│  ├─ Carousel.tsx
│  ├─ Category.tsx
│  ├─ DirectionalView.tsx
│  ├─ EditScreenInfo.tsx
│  ├─ ExternalLink.tsx
│  ├─ Heading.tsx
│  ├─ Product.tsx
│  ├─ StyledText.tsx
│  ├─ Themed.tsx
│  └─ __tests__
│     └─ StyledText-test.js
├─ constants
│  ├─ api.ts
│  ├─ Colors.ts
│  └─ site.ts
├─ i18n.tsx
├─ locales
│  ├─ ar.json
│  └─ en.json
├─ metro.config.js
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
├─ tsconfig.json
└─ yarn.lock
```

and this is my _layout.tsx

```
import FontAwesome from "@expo/vector-icons/FontAwesome";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {
  DarkTheme,
  DefaultTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
} from "@react-navigation/native";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import { SplashScreen, Stack } from "expo-router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useColorScheme } from "react-native";

export {
  // Catch any errors thrown by the Layout component.
  ErrorBoundary,
} from "expo-router";

export const unstable_settings = {
  // Ensure that reloading on `/modal` keeps a back button present.
  initialRouteName: "login",
};

// Prevent the splash screen from auto-hiding before asset loading is complete.
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

export default function RootLayout() {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    Rubik: require("../assets/fonts/Rubik-Regular.ttf"),
    Rubikm: require("../assets/fonts/Rubik-Medium.ttf"),
    Rubikb: require("../assets/fonts/Rubik-Bold.ttf"),
    ...FontAwesome.font,
  });

  // Expo Router uses Error Boundaries to catch errors in the navigation tree.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  if (!loaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return <RootLayoutNav />;
}

function RootLayoutNav() {
  const colorScheme = useColorScheme();

  return (
    <ThemeProvider value={colorScheme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
      <Stack>
        <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="modal" options={{ presentation: "modal" }} />
        <Stack.Screen name="login" />
      </Stack>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```